# "Fluide de travail" et "fluide travaillant" pour rendre le sens de "working fluid"

Tags: traduction, locutions, science, participe-présent, de

> The heat pump operates on the basis of a working fluid which changes state in a continuous cycle.
>
> La pompe à chaleur fonctionne sur la base d'un fluide de travail qui change d'état dans un cycle continu.

Pourquoi ne peut-on pas rendre en français **working fluid** avec **fluide travaillant** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il arrive parfois que le français utilise une structure similaire à celle de l'anglais *working fluid*, comme avec *chat errant* ou *bain moussant*, mais ça ne marche pas toujours très bien.

Ici, la forme :

> ...sur la base d'un fluide travaillant qui change d'état...

n'est pas du tout idiomatique.

La traduction proposée ne paraît cependant pas très fidèle à l'anglais, un *fluide de travail* ne voulant pas dire <s>grand chose, et en tout cas pas</s> qu'il travaille.

Il s'agit cependant de l'expression utilisée dans le jargon spécifique du domaine.

> En surface, le fluide géothermal est amené dans un échangeur de chaleur où il cède une partie de son énergie à un fluide volatile (alcane, HCFC...), appelé [**fluide de travail**](http://www.geothermie-perspectives.fr/image/principe-fonctionnement-dun-cycle-binaire), présentant la propriété de se vaporiser à basse température.

(www.geothermie-perspectives.fr)

Si l'on souhaite une expression plus générique, on peut utiliser *actif* pour rendre *working* :

> ...sur la base d'un fluide actif qui change d'état...

ou préciser en quoi consiste son travail :

> ...sur la base d'un fluide frigorigène, qui change d'état...

ou même de supprimer *working* puisque le reste de la phrase montre bien que le fluide joue un rôle central.

> ...sur la base d'un fluide qui change d'état...

Answer (score 5):

Je serais essentiellement d'accord avec les propos des autres réponses en ce qui a trait à l'idée qu'en langage usuel c'est l'idée de « qui fonctionne, adéquat, de mise » etc. pour *working* comme adjectif dans le sens « that works » sauf qu'il s'agit ici de terminologie ou de vocabulaire technique et on trouve le terme *working fluid* en génie [mécanique](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8881277)/[climatique](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=19471447), en [physique](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8474793) de la thermodynamique, en [astronautique](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=WORKING%20FLUID&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs), en [électricité](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8410545) etc. et on traduit par l'un des termes suivants :

> Fluide de travail, ...moteur, ...actif, ...caloporteur,
>   ...thermodynamique.

L'emploi de la forme *travaillant* emporte une confusion entre la [possibilité](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2915) d'avoir un adjectif verbal ou un participe présent sans complément ; de plus, « working fluid » forme une unité lexicale, tout comme ces traductions, et l'adjectif (non verbal) ou le complément du nom sont plus clairs.

Answer (score 2):

Les noms composés ne se construisent pas en français comme en anglais ; c'est la seule raison  ; voir par exemple les termes suivants et leur traductions ;

- filling station  (*américain*) ===> pas « station remplissant »,  station-service.
- working woman  ===> pas « femme travaillant », femme active
- working man ===> pas « homme travaillant », travailleur
- working party ===> pas « groupe travaillant », groupe de travail
- working order ===> pas « état marchant », état de marche